# How to determine objects move in any direction? with opencv and eclipse

Tags: android, opencv, object, detection, direction

I use OpenCV library with eclipse and programming by Java for Android.
How to determine objects move in any direction? For example, to
determine the hand or whatever... moving to the right or left. thanks in advance.

Comment: [optical flow](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/video/Video.html) might help you.

Comment: sorry, there's neither a java nor an android demo

Comment: Sure thnx for ur help ... but is there any other way rather than optical flow ?? any help using open cv on android ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using this algorithm:

1-Extract two images from your video.

2-Detect the position of your object.

3-compare the two positions.

4-Decide what is the moving direction.

Comment: All the steps are implemented in opencv